# Python close Loop for Chrome in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, pkill

I try this code, it runs proberly but doesnt kill chrome browser. What am i doing wrong?

```
    import schedule
    import time

def job():
    print("Kill Chrome in Progress..")
    'pkill chrome'
    print("Sucessfully killed Chrome")
schedule.every(0.5).minutes.do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: That's not how you run a console command. 
Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python

Comment: Thank you for Answering, i got it solved, now i search for a way to change the time of a delay any cycle :)

Comment: Check if that `schedule.every(0.5).minutes.do(job)` returns you an object.